# How to change the mouse cursor when it passes over a component but said component is disabled?

Tags: java, swing

I have the following line of code in the mouseEntered event of a JtextField:
txt.setCursor (Cursor.getSystemCustomCursor ("Invalid.32x32"));
If the component is enabled (setEnabled (true)) the changes are applied. But if it is disabled, nothing happens.
Any help would be great. From already thank you very much

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9073687/wait-cursor-and-disable-java-application).

Comment: thanks tomás !!
But I was able to figure out what I wanted to do by replacing "txt" with "this"

Comment: *"I was able to figure out what I wanted to do"* Please either answer the question below or delete it using the link below the tags. I suggest the 2nd, as this does not provide enough value for future visitors. Glad you got it sorted.